# Build failed with an exception - flutter A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception :

[image]

Hey, I'm new to flutter development. I wanted to run the demo app on my android device. But this error. I'm using Flutter 2.0.6. I tried my best to solve the issue. but I couldn't solve it. I'm using visual studio code. I ran the "flutter doctor" command and it says no issues found!

I checked `build.gradle` file as well. I even tweak some code in it as well, still, it did not work, So if anyone could help with the issue, it would be much appreciated.

- Thank you

`build.gradle` file code:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me your gradle version?

Comment: @ShreyanshSharma gradle:4.1.0.

Comment: Can you please check and tell me that, are your dependecies' versions are up-to-date or I can say, have you installed any packages (if) with their latest version?

Comment: @ShreyanshSharma actually I don't understand what packages you're talking about. But I can say this much, this was the first time I tried to run the flutter demo app on my android device. I installed all the necessary thing to run it, and I checked with the 'flutter doctor' command to make sure everything was alright. And there weren't any issues. Still, I get this error while trying to run the demo app.

Comment: Ohh, then try to upgrade your gradle version to 7.0 . Sometimes when we use a manually imported package from pub.dev, and it is a very older version, then this error comes. But since, it was your demo app, i think gradle version is too old (4.1.0) for flutter 2.0+ versions.